# How can I serialize None from db to empyt object?

Tags: django, django-serializer

I have the following models:

```
class ContentUpload(BaseModel):
    ...
    status = models.ForeignKey(CourseStatus, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="content_status", null=True, blank = True)
```

```
class CourseStatus(BaseModel):
    status_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.status_name)
        super(CourseStatus, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.status_name)
```

The following serializers:

```
class CourseStatusListSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CourseStatus
        fields = ('id', 'status_name', 'slug')
```

```
    def get_status(self, obj):
        return CourseStatusListSerializers(obj.status, context={"request": self.context['request']}).data
```

When the ContentUpload.status is None it returns the following:

```
"status":{"status_name":"","slug":""}
```

My question is that how can I do it to give back an empty object? What is your best practice for this?

```
"status":{}
```

Comment: I have a workaround
if obj.status:
    return CourseStatusListSerializers(obj.status).data
 return {}

But i dont like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1-** Rewrite your `ContentUploadSerializer` to the following:

```
class ContentUploadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    status = CourseStatusListSerializers(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = ContentUpload
        fields = ('id', 'status',)
```

**2-** Remove the `get_status` method.

The serialized `ContentUpload` object with the `status` field `None` will be as follows:

```
  {
    "id": 2,
    "status": null
  }
```

And with the `status` field not `None` it will be:

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "status": {
      "id": 1,
      "status_name": "Pending",
      "slug": "pending"
    }
  }
```

You can read more about the nested serializers from this page.
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects